# Cannot Add Script Component to Data Flow Task

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

Cannot add a Script Component to Data Flow Task for an SSIS Package that I am working on.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 and creating an SSIS Package that is targeted for SQL Server 2012
I am trying to drag the Script Component Task from the SSIS Toolbox to the Data Flow Task, I get the error as shown below

> TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The component could not be added to the Data Flow task. Could not
>   initialize the component. There is a potential problem in the
>   ProvideComponentProperties method.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error at Replace Delimiter in File [SSIS.Pipeline]: Failed to create
>   COM Component Categories Manager due to error 0x80070002 "The system
>   cannot find the file specified.".
>
> Error at Replace Delimiter in File [ [52]]: The component is missing,
>   not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The
>   contact information for this component is "".
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0048021
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> OK

The Script Component should be added to the Data Flow Task

Comment: I'd look to see if there are updates available for Visual Studio and/or SSDT. Barring that, you might try to rerun the SSDT installer and repair the installation

Comment: I tried that multiple times - not sure what the issue was but I ended up upgrading my license to Visual Studio 2019 and have not had any issues since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions - but I ended up upgrading my license to visual studio 2019 and it worked like a charm 
I guess because with this version the SSDT is integrated better
Not really entirely sure what the issue was with Visual Studio 2017 - it could be my install but because VS 2019 didn't work I did not bother with it.